# Adding row on the top using Angular - Xeditable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

I want by clicking in the "Add row" button the new row will be on the top table.
I have this basic **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/653/)**.

I tried to add a filter to the function bellow, but I got hte same result.

```
// add user
$scope.addUser = function() {
  $scope.inserted = {
    id: $scope.users.length+1,
    name: '',
    status: null,
    group: null 
  };
  $scope.users.push($scope.inserted);
};
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) instead of push so that the item is added to the start of the array:

```
    $scope.users.unshift($scope.inserted);
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/NfPcH/919/)</kbd>